# What do the flags in crontabs mean?

Tags: php

I have this line in my crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php5 -d allow_url_fopen=on -f /path/to/file.php
```

I cannot find any comprehensive reference on the meaning of the "-d" and "-f" flags. What do they mean? And is there a page that explains these and other flags?

Comment: They're nothing to do with crontab. Everything after the first 5 fields is just a shell command line.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

```
-d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
-f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
```

So this means that file `/path/to/file.php` should be executed with `allow_url_fopen` option set on.

Answer (score 5):

The flags relate to the php5 command.

-d defines a variable
-f sets the file to execute

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/php/